# Unable to use Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the following error when trying to create object with Selenium Webdriver.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\path", line 15, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

This is how my code looks like until line 15:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import random

#OPCIONES
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
opts.add_argument("--headless")

#DRIVER
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)
```

By the way, I have already tried to don't use chrome options and got the same error, and finally my selenium version is 4.12.0, and this is what is having me crazy. It is suppose to work only using

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

in this version.

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestions at the URL that is printed in your error message?

Comment: Sure I did. In fact thats the reason why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase framework and driver manager:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome")
driver.get("https://my-user-agent.com/")
print(driver.wait_for_element("#ua_string").text)
driver.quit()

# Lots of customization options!
driver = Driver(headless=True, agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
driver.get("https://my-user-agent.com/")
print(driver.wait_for_element("#ua_string").text)
driver.quit()
```

For more `Driver()` args, see [seleniumbase/plugins/driver_manager.py](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/plugins/driver_manager.py).